# Rendering Problems NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors

Tags: android, rendering

I am getting this error on Android Studio.

Rendering Problems NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.
The following classes could not be found:

```
<com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Tip: Try to build the project.

And here is my XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_container"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottombar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_shadow_up"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottombar_height"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottombar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added the dependencies for custom views in project's gradle file.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Seems like you are using a third party library for BottomBar (com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar). For that you need to add its library in your gradle file (one which is in your project). e.g. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'

Comment: I have 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' in my gradle file

Comment: That was just an example showing how to add a dependency in build.gradle. What you need to add is the dependency for 'com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar'. Did you copy the code from somewhere?

Comment: Let me simplify. Error you are getting is bcoz compiler is not able to identify ur class 'com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view.BottomBar'. In this case, there are 2 possibilities. Either you are using a 3rd party library that have this custom class defined or this custom class is defined in your project itself. If it is a 3rd party library then ask your provider to tell library name and version and add it in gradle like 'compile <library>:<version>' and re-sync project. If this custom class is defined in ur project itself, then define it at location com.makeuprewardz.app.ui.view. I hope it clarifies.